# Place CSS and Javascript outside EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, deployment, websphere, ibm-rad

I have a web application deployed in IBM websphere. Each time I change my css or javascript file I have to redeploy EAR file. Is it possible to place these css/javascript files outside EAR/WAR file so that I can avoid redeploying EAR file.

Comment: Dynamic reloading is the ability to change an existing component without needing to restart the server. And i think its an advantange.  Are you asking w.r.t IDEs deployment?

Comment: I am using RAd for development. Can you give me any link for what you are talking about?

Comment: Since you seem to be talking specifically about doing this in/from RAD, I've added the RAD tag to the question.

Comment: Are you only wanting to change the behavior while running within RAD or also when running on a separate server with artifacts that you built from within RAD?

Comment: Also when running on a separate server with artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that pattern, I recommend placing those static files in a different location on your web server (or proxy server if you have one), then referencing them from your pages with a path Alias. For instance in Apache/IHS:

```
Alias /css /usr/IBM/HTTPServer/htdocs/css
```

And then in your HTML/JSP:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Utility Application as Dynamic Web Project and place all the css,images and script files inside it. you can create a seperate WAR outside EAR. your files inside EAR can refer to this WAR file for the resources, but you have to take care of the context-path. 
Here you can avoid of complete building of EAR file but you need to build WAR file. Accessing the css/js/images outside WAR and EAR doesnt sound a correct way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) you can map the resources that reside in an arbitrary location. So once you make any changes to the resources, these will be visible in the app instantly.

Answer (score 0):

deploy your ear as an "Exploded Archive Directories"

see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/deployment/deployunits.html

then you can just copy the static files and move on

websphere seems to support it to, at least for the war part
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/discover/v8r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ii.product.ce.doc/configuring/iiyviigdepwebexpl.htm

Comment: Thanks but does IBM websphere allow this deployment?